# Allow special characters in search url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I tried to find answer but without success.

When I search for Mädchen I get the following URL:

`http://www.example.com/search/M%25C3%25A4dchen`, how can I get the URL like this one:

`http://www.example.com/search/Mädchen`

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]

RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\+([^+]*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)$ /search.php?key=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?key=([^\s]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [R=301,L]\
```

Comment: It's double escaping the characters so I assume you're doing multiple redirects rather than one. What happens if you change the last regex from `^` to `!^search/`?

Comment: Problem sloved, i just added NE here
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [R=301,NE,L]

Comment: Seems like you've resolved a symptom but not the cause.